# How to open a record in DetailView using Oid in XAF WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xaf, xpo

I need to open an existing record in DetailView by taking Oid as user input in a textbox.

I have created a custom form and put a textbox and a button to take value of Oid from user and then submit it. I can find the object but I don't know the exact syntax of the function that will display the found object in a detail view.

```
        uow = new UnitOfWork();

        op = CriteriaOperator.Parse("Oid = ?", ContactOIDTextBox.Text);

        contact = objSpace.FindObject<Contact>(CriteriaOperator.Parse("Oid = ?", ContactOIDTextBox.Text));

        if (contact== null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not found");
        }

        else
        {
            //this should display the found object in a detail view
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `ShowView` method like

```cs
Application.ShowViewStrategy.ShowView(new ShowViewParameters(Application.FindModelView(Application.FindDetailViewId(typeof(Contact)))),new ShowViewSource(null,null) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I am getting the following error:
'Application' does not contain a definition for 'ShowViewStrategy'

Comment: Please follow the docs https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112803/concepts/ui-construction/views/ways-to-show-a-view#3). or ask in DevExpresss Support Center, they will answer you within the day. I just tried to guide you.